# Better options to show Open and Save option for each file in a list

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, buttons, icons

[image]

A list of all input files is shown. User can click ‘Create Output Files’ to create output files for each input file.

[image]

Now when all output files are created, ‘Create Output Files’ button becomes disabled. Now user can either Open output file or Save output files for created against each input file. 
How can this be shown on UI? Simplest approach can be to shown separate Open and Save options for each output file but this doesn’t look good on UI. Can there be any better approach to do this?

Comment: What are input and output files? If Output file is an image, showing thumbnail in place of 'Open Output File' link is a good idea, show full image if user clicks on thumbnail.

Comment: Output file can be a PDF or txt. and how to give the option of Save/download if I give thumbnail for opening the output file?

Answer (score 2):

Provide thumbnail for quick view, clicking on the thumbnail opens full image in a new browser tab.

Provide a download overlay icon on top of each thumbnail for pick and download.
Also provide 'Download All' action at some corner to download/save all output file.

Providing thumbnail for pdf/text is possible.

Please refer to below Gmail attachment screenshot to get clear :-

[image: Down arrow clicking saves that file to local FS]